# Is protein shake diet good?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, muscle-gain, protein-shakes

I am 100kg, 196cm tall, 26 y.o, male.

I am trying a diet consisting of:

- Breakfast - Anabolic Protein shake (not mentioning brand intentionally)

  - 564 kCal
  - 53g Protein
  - 81g Carbs
  - 2.6 Fat
- Lunch - Vegetables + source of fat (cheese / fish / avocado / etc) (200-400kCal)
- Snack - Fruit / Nuts
- Dinner (Post Workout meal) - Anabolic Protein shake - same as breakfast.

I am trying to both gain lean muscle tissue and reduce body fat. As the shakes are quite calorie rich I try to stick to them for breakfast / dinner.

Is this type of diet healthy / sufficient for what I am intending to achieve?

Comment: It looks like an OK plan for losing some fat quickly while retaining the muscle mass if you also take some multivitamins/minerals. It is probably a bad idea to follow it long-term - see Jun Kang's answer.

Answer (score 6):

No this is not healthy or sufficient. At 100kg/220lbs, 196cm/6ft5in, 26 y/o male, your caloric intake is pretty low. At those numbers, I would expect your maintenance level to be ~2600 calories (guestimate). If you're going to the gym, which I assume you are since you said 'Dinner (Post workout meal)', this will be even higher. Even estimating high, your daily calories right now is ~1800 tops, ~1100 of that being from your protein shakes. But my biggest problem with this diet is with the protein shakes themselves.

There are some fantastic protein shake brands out there, but protein shakes are supplements, and supplements only. They shouldn't be used to replace your meals outright. Eating whole foods is the best way to get all the nutrients you need to gain muscle/lose fat. I know replacing meals with protein shakes is convenient and easy, and I might recommend someone do that for breakfast (if they don't regularly eat breakfast or something), but not for breakfast AND dinner. You lose out on tons of vitamins and minerals you can only really get from whole foods. Supplementing should only be used as means to make it easier to reach your macro/calorie goals, to **"supplement your diet."** Not to act as the bulk of your diet.

Gaining both lean muscle tissue and losing fat is very hard, and a widely controversial topic. Many people believe its impossible to do both at the same time, since you need to be at a deficit to lose fat, and at a surplus to gain muscle. Personally, through just personal experience, I think you can do both at the same time if you just maintain a healthy diet and keep up the exercise, but that's just my opinion.

Proteins - Get lots of protein, preferably from whole foods (meats, beans, nuts, fish, etc) and supplement with protein shakes if you find it hard to reach your protein macro goals. 
Carbs - Are NOT your enemy. Eat low-moderate GOOD carbs (oats, beans, brown rice, etc). 
Fats - Are NOT your enemy. Eat low-moderate GOOD fats (fish, olive oil, nuts, avocados, etc). 
Veggies - Veggies are typically very low in calories, but pack a ton of essential vitamins and nutrients. Get lots of veggies in your diet.

I was also in your position, though not as tall as you, and this is what I did to lose fat and gain muscle. I ate healthy whole foods, supplementing with whey protein. I ate at just under maintenance calories. So if my maintenance calories was 2000 (before exercise), for example, I would aim to eat 1900 calories per day. That way, I would be at a deficit of 100 calories + however many calories I burned during exercise, around 400 calorie deficit total daily. Lastly, lift heavy 3-4 times a week.

One last note: don't go crazy with the diet. The best diet is something you can maintain and stick with. If you drive yourself crazy because you cut sugar cold turkey, you WILL cave and binge on sugar. Do something you can stick with long term. If you LOVE sodas, like me, maybe instead of cutting out sodas completely, try to have 1 of those mini soda cans a day. And then cut it down to 1 every other day. This isn't a short term goal. Its a life choice. And it will take time to reach your goals.

Comment: Additionally, at 26 years old, you should really be striving to build the dietary habits that will serve you for a lifetime. Protein shakes may have a place during periods of very heavy muscle-building workout, if you need to supplement your protein and calorie intake, but it's just not a healthy habit to make that a standard meal replacement. The advice in this post -- to concentrate on balanced meals of whole foods -- will set up good habits and tastes for the long term.